# Solr - Active/Passive mode for data core and deleting stale data

Tags: solr

We get a feed file nightly which is loaded to Solr through "update" API (http://localhost:8983/solr/data_core/update?stream.file=). We can only data stale data once current file is successfully loaded to Solr.

Currently, we are using Solr 6.1.0 in our development phase, so we have setup with 2 Shards and replication factor as 2.

**Question**

How can we have active/passive instance of SOlr core while active instance (with stale data) is open to business, we can load data from file to passive instance and once the load of file is successful switch the active instance to new one?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new core with the same schema and config as your current one (*data_core*). Let's call it *data_core2*.
Then your nightly update process can load this one and, after completion of this process, you can use the APIs to swap between the two cores, this way:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=SWAP&core=data_core&other=data_core2
```

*data_core* will be available for searches during the whole time

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering my question. How can I use this passive/active mode in Solr Cloud env. Collection doesn't offer SWAP action correct? Do I have to create alias for collections (active and passive) and swap the alias names once data load is done? Pls let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Yes you can use the same mechanism in the solr cloud environment, since the swap action is available there as well. Just send thr SWAP command to one of the nodes and this should work as expected. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, Can you kindly point to documentation or example for COLLECTION SWAP please? When I tried to find, I could only find SWAP functionality for CORE but not COLLECTION. Thanks again!